# 'module is not defined' error is displayed when using sprockets-commonjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, sprockets, commonjs

I've been trying to get sprockets-commonjs to work on my rails project for a while now with no luck.

This is what I am doing:

**Gemfile**

```
...

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'http://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
gem "ember-rails", :git => "https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails.git", :branch => "master"
gem 'sprockets-commonjs'

...
```

**app/assets/javascripts/hello.module.js**

```
 module.exports = function () {
       return "hello world!";
      };
```

This is what I am getting when I run the application:

Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined .

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

So I just had a similar issue. Can you post the place where you're requiring the module?

My gut is either you're only requiring it once, or not requiring it at all.

Also ensure you're requiring `name.module` instead of just `name`. Oh, and you have to also require it like a normal commonjs module in the code too (ie using just `name`)

Answer (score 0):

The following fixed this error for me (although I'm still having trouble requiring my modules):

stop the rails server
rm -rf tmp/cache
start the rails server

Source:

https://github.com/maccman/sprockets-commonjs/issues/4